# number of balanced binary trees

Tags: binary-trees

How you can find the number of balanced binary tree knowing only the number of nodes? Is there a method better than generate all possible balanced trees and if not how can i generate those trees based only on the number of nodes?

Comment: What is a balanced binary tree for you?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

Comment: i do not understand what that guy did there with that recursive formula

Comment: Then you should ask that guy. We don't answer the same question twice.